# PHP, MySQL - how to parameterize timestamp comparisons

Tags: php, mysql

I have $year and $month, and I need to select all records where a timestamp is after one year/month and before another year/month

```
WHERE m.id = :magazineId
      AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
      AND t.`timestamp` >= STR_TO_DATE(:year'-08-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
      AND t.`timestamp` < STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Just to get started I sub'd out just one of the year entries and the query stopped finding any rows.

How is one supposed to parameterize this?

Comment: I think that just putting that `:year` parameter right before the string is not valid SQL. Since it's a string you're prepending it to, you should concatenate it: `CONCAT(:year, '-08-01')`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using:

```
`t`.`timestamp` BETWEEN "$DATE1" AND "$DATE2"?
```

[MySQL Between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

You might also want to try instead of using STR_TO_DATE, converting your date to a timestamp

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "world");
$mymagazineid = "Foo";
$year = "2013";

$parameter_clause = <<<EOD
   SELECT * FROM YourTable
   WHERE m.id = ?
   AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
   AND t.`timestamp` >= STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d')
   AND t.`timestamp` < STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
EOD;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $parameter_clause);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mymagazineid, "$year-08-01");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$date1 = strtotime('01-08-$year');
$date2 = strtotime('01-09-2013');

$query = "SELECT * from your_table WHERE m.id = '{$magazineId}' AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
  AND t.`timestamp` BETWEEN  '{$date1}' AND '{$date2}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially (without the PDO parameter for the sake of the example)

PHP

```
$target = $year . '/' . $month . '/01';
```

SQL

```
" ...
WHERE m.id = :magazineId
AND t.isChargedBack IS FALSE
AND t.`timestamp` >= '$target'
AND t.`timestamp` < DATEADD('$target' + 1 MONTH);"
```